Flutter: customepaint and gesture out of sync when offscreen
I am developing a node editor sort of app, in which you can add nodes and connect them with a noodle connection (like in blender and Unreal engine), I am facing a problem when a node is dragged off screen, and then I pan the screen to it, then when i try to drag from the output circle (to create a new connection line) the line endpoint is not at the same place as my finger gesture (using onpanupdate details.globalposition)
class MyMindMapWidgetState extends State<MyMindMap>
    with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  double _scale = 1.0;
  Offset _offset = Offset.zero;
  Offset _initialFocalPoint = Offset.zero;
  Offset _offsetOnScaleStart = Offset.zero;
  Offset _toolbarOffset = Offset.zero;
  double _toolBarScale = 1;
  Offset nodeOffset = Offset.zero;
  Offset outputOffset = Offset.zero;
  Offset inputOffset = Offset.zero;

  final bool _staticBackground = false;

  void _handleScaleStart(ScaleStartDetails details) {
    setState(() {
      _initialFocalPoint = details.localFocalPoint;
      _offsetOnScaleStart = _offset;
    });
  }

  void _handleScaleUpdate(ScaleUpdateDetails details) {
    final double newScale = _scale * details.scale;
    late double sensitivity = 0.05;

    final double scaleDelta = (newScale - _scale) * sensitivity;
    final double clampedScale = (_scale + scaleDelta).clamp(0.3, 3);

    // Calculate the normalized offset
    final Offset normalizedOffset =
        (_initialFocalPoint - _offsetOnScaleStart) / _scale;
    setState(() {
      _scale = clampedScale;
      _offset = details.localFocalPoint - normalizedOffset * _scale;
    });
  }

  void _resetOffsetAndScale() {
    setState(() {
      _scale = 1.0;
      _offset = Offset.zero;
      _toolbarOffset = Offset.zero;
      _toolBarScale = 1;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // Call the function to make the app full screen
    fullScreenMode();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // Reset the system UI mode when the widget is disposed
    fullScreenMode();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    fullScreenMode();
    return BlocListener<NodeConnectionCubit, NodeConnectionState>(
      listener: (context, state) {
        if (state is NodeConnectionUpdatedState) {
          setState(() {});
        }
      },
      child: Container(
        color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 26, 26, 23),
        child: GestureDetector(
          onScaleStart: _handleScaleStart,
          onScaleUpdate: _handleScaleUpdate,
          onDoubleTap: _resetOffsetAndScale,
          child: CustomPaint(
            painter: !_staticBackground
                ? DynamicBackground(_offset)
                : StaticBackground(),
            child: BlocBuilder<NodeCubit, NodeState>(
              builder: (context, state) {
                if (state is NodeUpdatedState) {
                  return BlocBuilder<NodeConnectionCubit, NodeConnectionState>(
                    builder: (context, connectionState) {
                      if (connectionState is NodeConnectionUpdatedState) {
                        return Stack(
                          fit: StackFit.expand,
                          children: [
                            Transform(
                              transform:
                                  Matrix4.diagonal3Values(_scale, _scale, 1.0)
                                    ..translate(_offset.dx, _offset.dy),
                              child: DeferredPointerHandler(
                                child: DeferPointer(
                                  child: Stack(
                                    children: [
                                      for (int paintIndex = 0;
                                          paintIndex <
                                              connectionState
                                                  .linkedNodes.length;
                                          paintIndex++)
                                        CustomPaint(
                                          painter: NodeLinkPainter(
                                            color: Colors.teal.withOpacity(0.5),
                                            connection: connectionState
                                                .linkedNodes[paintIndex],
                                            repaint: context
                                                .watch<NodeConnectionCubit>(),
                                          ),
                                          child:
                                              Container(), // This is crucial for CustomPaint to take effect
                                        ),
                                      for (int index = 0;
                                          index <
                                              context
                                                  .read<NodeCubit>()
                                                  .nodeList
                                                  .length;
                                          index++)
                                        MyNode(
                                          index: index,
                                        ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),

class MyNodeState extends State<MyNode> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final NodeCubit nodeCubit = context.watch<NodeCubit>();
    final NodeConnectionCubit connectionCubit =
        context.read<NodeConnectionCubit>();
    Offset widgetOffset = nodeCubit.getOffsets()[widget.index!];
    late String? inputID = nodeCubit.nodeList[widget.index!].inputId;
    final NodeUtils nodeUtils = NodeUtils();

    return BlocBuilder<NodeCubit, NodeState>(
      builder: (context, state) {
        if (state is NodeUpdatedState) {
          // list of nodes
          final nodeList = state.nodes;
          final node = nodeList[widget.index!];
          final inputOffsets = nodeList.map((e) => e.nodeInput).toList();
          Offset? inputOffset;

          return Transform.translate(
            filterQuality: FilterQuality.high,
            offset: widgetOffset,
            child: DeferPointer(
              child: GestureDetector(
                onPanUpdate: (details) {
                  setState(() {
                    // Update _widgetOffset with current drag position
                    widgetOffset = Offset(widgetOffset.dx + details.delta.dx,
                        widgetOffset.dy + details.delta.dy);
                    context
                        .read<NodeCubit>()
                        .updateOffset(node.id, widgetOffset);
                    var outputOffset = node.nodeOutput;
                    connectionCubit.linkedNodes.forEach((e) {
                      if (node.id == e.outputId) {
                        context.read<NodeConnectionCubit>().updateConnection(
                            node.id, outputOffset, node.id, inputOffset);
                      }
                    });
                  });
                },
                child: BlocBuilder<NodeConnectionCubit, NodeConnectionState>(
                  builder: (context, connectionState) {
                    if (connectionState is NodeConnectionUpdatedState) {
                      // var connections = connectionState.linkedNodes;
                      return Stack(
                        alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center,
                        children: [
                          //Node Base Color and Style.
                          Container(
                            height: node.height?.toDouble(),
                            width: node.width?.toDouble(),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              // color: Color(0xFF212121).withAlpha(240),
                              boxShadow: [
                                BoxShadow(color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.1))
                              ],
                              border: Border.all(
                                color: Theme.of(context)
                                    .colorScheme
                                    .surface
                                    .withOpacity(0.025),
                                strokeAlign: BorderSide.strokeAlignInside,
                                width: 1,
                              ),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(2),
                            ),
                            child: Column(
                              children: [
                                Expanded(
                                    flex: 2,
                                    child: Container(
                                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                          color: Theme.of(context)
                                              .cardColor
                                              .withOpacity(0.95),
                                          borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                                              Radius.circular(2))),
                                    )),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          //Node Output
                          GestureDetector(
                            onPanStart: (details) {
                              setState(() {
                                inputOffset = details.globalPosition;
                                print("starting at ... $inputOffset");
                                final existingConnections = connectionCubit
                                    .linkedNodes
                                    .where((connection) =>
                                        connection.outputId == node.id)
                                    .toList();
                                var outputOffset = nodeCubit
                                    .getOutputOffsets(node.id)[widget.index!];
                                if (existingConnections.isNotEmpty) {
                                  // ignore: unused_local_variable
                                  for (var connection in existingConnections) {
                                    connectionCubit.updateConnection(node.id,
                                        outputOffset, inputID, inputOffset);
                                  }
                                } else {
                                  // Add new connection if none exist
                                  connectionCubit.addConnection(node.id,
                                      outputOffset, inputID, inputOffset);
                                }
                              });
                            },
                            onPanUpdate: (details) {
                              setState(() {
                                inputOffset = details.globalPosition;
                                late final snapOffset =
                                    nodeUtils.snapToClosestOffset(
                                        inputOffset!, inputOffsets, 20);

                                if (snapOffset != null) {
                                  inputOffset = snapOffset;
                                } else {
                                  inputOffset = details.globalPosition;
                                }
                                final existingConnections = connectionCubit
                                    .linkedNodes
                                    .where((connection) =>
                                        connection.outputId == node.id)
                                    .toList();
                                var outputOffset = nodeCubit
                                    .getOutputOffsets(node.id)[widget.index!];
                                if (existingConnections.isNotEmpty) {
                                  // ignore: unused_local_variable
                                  for (var connection in existingConnections) {
                                    connectionCubit.updateConnection(node.id,
                                        outputOffset, inputID, inputOffset);
                                  }
                                } else {
                                  // Add new connection if none exist
                                  connectionCubit.addConnection(node.id,
                                      outputOffset, inputID, inputOffset);
                                }

                                print(
                                    'this is the updated outputOffset ${inputOffsets}');
                              });
                            },
                            child: NodeInputOutput(
                              alignment: AlignmentDirectional.centerEnd,
                              nodeheight: node.height!.toDouble(),
                              nodeWidth: node.width!.toDouble() + 10,
                              dotHeight: 10,
                              dotWidth: 10,
                              offsetX: 0,
                              // offsetY: -24,
                              borderWidth: 0.5,
                            ),
                          ),
                      ...etc


void addNode(String? id, String? label, Offset? nodeOffset, Offset? nodeInput,
      Offset? nodeOutput, int? height, int? width, String? type, bool? isDone) {
    String defaultLabel = "Node ${nodeList.length + 1}";
    label ??= defaultLabel;
    height ??= 80;
    width ??= 120;

    //  position for the new node
    nodeOffset = nodeutils?.calculateNewNodePosition(
        nodeList, Size(width.toDouble(), height.toDouble()));
    nodeOutput =
        Offset(nodeOffset!.dx + (width + 5), nodeOffset.dy + (height / 2 + 2));
    nodeInput = Offset(nodeOffset.dx + 5, nodeOffset.dy + (height / 2 + 2));
    nodeList.add(Node(
        id: id!,
        inputId: "${id}-input",
        outputId: "${id}-output",
        label: defaultLabel,
        offset: nodeOffset,
        nodeInput: nodeInput,
        nodeOutput: nodeOutput,
        height: height,
        width: width,
        type: type!,
        isdone: isDone));

    emit(NodeUpdatedState(nodeList));

    idController.clear();
    labelController.clear();
    heightController.clear();
    widthController.clear();
  }

  void updateOffset(String? nodeId, Offset? newOffset) {
    for (var node in nodeList) {
      final newNodeOutputOffset = Offset(newOffset!.dx + (node.width! + 5),
          newOffset.dy + (node.height! / 2 + 2));
      final newNodeInputOffset =
          Offset(newOffset.dx + 5, newOffset.dy + (node.height! / 2 + 2));
      if (node.id == nodeId) {
        final updatedNode = node.copyWith(
            offset: newOffset,
            nodeOutput: newNodeOutputOffset,
            nodeInput: newNodeInputOffset);
        nodeList[nodeList.indexOf(node)] = updatedNode;
      }
    }
    emit(NodeUpdatedState(nodeList));
  }

void addConnection(String? outputId, Offset? outputOffset, String? inputId,
      Offset? inputOffset) {
    List<NodeConnection> newLinkedNodes = [...linkedNodes];
    newLinkedNodes.add(NodeConnection(
      inputId: inputId ?? const Uuid().v4(),
      outputId: outputId,
      inputOffset: inputOffset,
      outputOffset: outputOffset,
      connectionOn: true,
    ));
    linkedNodes = [...newLinkedNodes];
    emit(NodeConnectionUpdatedState(newLinkedNodes));
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void updateConnection(String? outputId, Offset? outputOffset, String? inputId,
      Offset? inputOffset) {
    for (var connection in linkedNodes) {
      if (connection.outputId == outputId &&
          connection.outputOffset != outputOffset) {
        connection.outputOffset = outputOffset;
      }
      if (connection.inputId == inputId &&
          connection.inputOffset != inputOffset) {
        connection.inputOffset = inputOffset;
      }
    }
    emit(NodeConnectionUpdatedState(linkedNodes));
    notifyListeners();
  }

i already faced a similar problem in the past, and it was fixed with deferpointer but now I tried that, I tried moving the custompaint outside the stack, I tried to use flow instead of stack and a multitude of solutions but the problem still remains,
here is a video showing the problem.
https://vimeo.com/989014777?share=copy
sorry about the bad quality.

I have fixed it before it was even published haha the solution is simple, here is the main fix "inputOffset = _globalToLocal(details.globalPosition);" " Offset _globalToLocal(Offset globalPosition) { RenderBox renderBox = context.findRenderObject() as RenderBox; return renderBox.globalToLocal(globalPosition); }" not sure why this works but details.localPosition doesn't but if it works it works haha, please mark this as answered, have a great day my friends.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
